# Remove Class from Home Page

Tags: html, jquery, css

I would like to remove the following from the HOMPE PAGE ONLY!
I have access to page editor but not sure what to insert in the CSS editor on that page.
I want to remove the below:

```
<div class="fs_img_header header_video_fs_view" style="width: 1028px; height: 789px;"><div class="stat_img_cont" style="background-image: url();background-size: cover;background-position: center center;"></div></div>
```

Comment: You want to keep the div and remove the styling? Also, do not use in line styling it is bad practice.

Comment: `$('.fs_img_header').remove();`

Comment: The homepage of what? WordPress? Squarespace? Drupal?

Comment: https://sb.stonesoftsolutions.com/

Comment: I dont want the container area between the header and first pink body container... ONLY ON THE HOME PAGE.  Its for slider or video by default but I dont want it.

Comment: WordPress Site see URL above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.fs_img_header, .header_video_fs_view, .stat_img_cont {
   display: none;
}
```

if you're using Wordpress and the css has no effect:

```
.fs_img_header, .header_video_fs_view, .stat_img_cont {
   display: none !important;
}
```

To display it only on the homepage use following plugin (easy-way):
https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/css-javascript-toolbox/

With this plugin you can choose where it displays your custom css (in this case the homepage).

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Noel, the "!important;" generated a warning "use of strong".  should I be concerned? (WP CSS)

Comment: Most of the time wordpress or the plugins have their CSS at the end of the source code and the custom CSS you make mostly in the header, so your CSS will be automatically overridden again (CSS specification that are below override the previous ones).

Using !important overwrites all subsequent CSS specifications. Using !important on a real web page with HTML/CSS is not needed, because you build the CSS from scratch.

So you can ignore the warning.